# How can I change a Bool variable in one function from another?

Tags: python, function, boolean

I'm currently having some issues regarding Bools. I'm creating [a game](https://github.com/Snicklezs/Abduction/blob/master/Abductionv2.py) after getting to ex35 in Learn Python The Hard Way.

In my game there is two functions that I'm having trouble with (roomOne, and getFood), one function brings you to another and you are then given the option to pick up a brick of food - which you will later use to throw at a switch to disable the electric field around you.

I want the user to only be able to throw the food if he actually has the food on his person... Currently - with the way my program is set up - It does not matter if the user actually has the food - he can throw it either way. I've tried to return foodBrick = True or (==) in the get food function. But it has not worked out.

How can I fix my game so I can only turn off the switch only when the foodBrick is on my person?

Comment: `if  'throw' in throw` is enough right now, but `Foodbrick = True` should also be required. Please read up on asking a minimal question.

Comment: Okay. I just looked up 'minimal question'. Sorry, I will try to keep it shorter next time! And thank you for your input.

Comment: Please include code directly in the question (not in a link, because links change and then questions become useless).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your immediate problem is because you are always setting foodBrick = True, no matter what the user types in your `getFood()` subroutine.

You've done a bunch of work, so I'll suggest that you look at the code and see if you can identify anything that you are doing repeatedly, and see if you can make those common things into a subroutine.

Past that, I think you should consider making the player an object (member of a class) or a dictionary, so that you can add attributes to the player in different subroutines, and have them be visible throughout. Something like:

```
player['hasFood'] = True
```

or

```
player.has_food = True
```

depending on how you implement it.

Comment: Thanks! I haven't learned anything about classes yet, but I flipped a couple more pages through my book and found a page on them - I will be giving it a read tonight. I appreciate the help. :D

Comment: You could start out with just an empty dictionary at module scope (not indented at all): `Player = { }`